# iPhone displaying random codes on website

Tags: iphone, ios7, web, ios8, mobile-safari

I'm unable to figure out why there are random codes being shown in various places on this website. It doesn't happen on other websites. It also doesn't seem to happen on Android devices. It doesn't happen when connected to WiFi. On one iPhone with iOS8 it doesn't have it, but on another it does. On another iPhone with IOS7, it has it. I can't make any sense out of the codes. Any ideas?

See image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdblN.png

Comment: After taking a look at the tcpdump, it looks like there is a header (x-acr) sent by the carrier that is being sent that may be truncating. For whatever reason, this is causing the chunk data to be displayed on the page result.

Answer (score 0):

http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/10/verizon-wireless-injects-identifiers-link-its-users-to-web-requests/

As your comment suggests you might be seeing a tracking ID from your ISP, AT&T in this case.

Verizon uses the UIDH field which identifies someone to Ad services. It is essentially double-dipping, when the customer is also the product. Not to mention some website receives this header, combines user-provided data with the field, then selling this to someone else... Easiest data-collection strategy of their lives.